# Meta box data is saved but NOT displayed in the meta box text field. Why?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, post-meta

I have a custom post type and I created it using the following code.

```
/* DRAMAS */
register_post_type('dramas', array(
    'label' => 'Dramas',
    'show_ui' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'description'),
    'labels' => array (
        'name' => 'Dramas',
        'singular_name' => 'Drama',
        'menu_name' => 'Dramas'
    ),
) );
```

Following code for the meta box mark up

```
<?php
function custom_meta_box_markup() {
    $meta_box_text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta-box-text' );
    ?>
        <div>
            <label for="meta-box-text">Day</label>
            <input name="meta-box-text" type="text" value="<?php if ($meta_box_text) { echo $meta_box_text; }?>">
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

And my meta box code is:

```
function add_custom_meta_box()
{
    $id             = 'demo-meta-box';
    $title          = 'Schedule';
    $callback       = 'custom_meta_box_markup';
    $screen         = 'dramas';
    $context        = 'side';
    $priority       = 'high';
    $callback_args  = 'null';
    add_meta_box($id, $title, $callback, $screen, $context, $priority, $callback_args);
}

add_action("add_meta_boxes", "add_custom_meta_box");
```

Now I see the meta box like this:

[image: META BOX SCREEN SHOT]

I am able update the values and publish the post now.
But when I add a some thing in the above metabox and publish it, it is displayed on the custom field right after my editor. **NOT displayed** on the (schedule) meta box (day) field.

[image: custom filed]

Why is this? how can I solve this?

Comment: Thy this on markup function `$meta_box_text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta-box-text', true );`

Comment: I tried already. NO luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
function custom_meta_box_markup() {
    global $post;
    $meta_box_text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta-box-text', true );
    ?>
        <div>
            <label for="meta-box-text">Day</label>
            <input name="meta-box-text" type="text" value="<?php echo $meta_box_text;?>">
        </div>
<?php }
```

You are missing the `$post` global variable which holds the post data.

Comment: ishh,, that simple thing **global $post**... day saved.. Thanks a lot Abhik..

Comment: @FoolishCoder yeah, that happens to the best of us. Please accept it as the answer if that solved your issue.